# PHP Skip row CSV file

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I would like to skip all rows of csv file that are like this:

```
[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
```

My code is this:

```
        <?php
     //apro il file

    if (($fp = fopen($file, "r")) !== false)
{


    //per ogni riga del file...
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {

    //...inserisco una riga nella tabella
        $echo_tabella .= "<tr>";

        //Non tengo conto della prima riga del file CSV ma parto dalla seconda dove ci sono i valori
        if ($contatore_cicli_CSV_esterno!=0){

            foreach( $data as $el )

                $echo_tabella .= "<td>".$el."</td>";
        $echo_tabella .= "</tr>";
        $array_righe_CSV[] = $data; }}?>
```

Below in the code I added commands to see the array:

```
<?php
         //Per visualizzare la struttura dell'array
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($array_righe_CSV); // $righe CONTIENE LE RIGHE, es.:
            echo '</pre>';
  ?>
```

The output is:

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 192.168.234.147
        [1] => Z6QTB1BCA0003ZR 
        [2] => 742149
        [3] => 161
        [4] => 1132
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 192.168.234.147
        [1] => Z6QTB1BCA0003ZR 
        [2] => 945141
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($array_righe_CSV))
{
    print_r($array_righe_CSV);
}
```

Wouldn't this work ?